# moov atom not found

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, mp4, handbrake, hls

I downloaded [this video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M8gJMd_-OhX6qJD5KTxBHkavU64w-_WY) using youtube-dl's HLS downloader. The video was being HLS streamed using AES-128. Even though I could view it perfectly fine when it was being streamed in the browser, VLC doesn't play the downloaded video file. It doesn't seem to contain any metadata or codec information either. It's actually a 2hr 49min 10sec long video.

I thought re-encoding it with ffmpeg might solve the issue. But ffmpeg throws these exceptions irrespective of the operation I try to perform:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002a477298a80] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002a477298a80] moov atom not found
4.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Google search led me to tools such qtfaststart and mp4box. But none of them seemed to solve the issue.

- Running `qtfaststart 4.mp4 41.mp4` throws the `moov atom not found, is this a valid MOV/MP4 file?` exception
- Running `MP4Box -add 4.mp4 41.mp4`, `MP4Box -inter 0 4.mp4` or `MP4Box -add 4.h265 41.mp4` show exceptions such as:

  - Incomplete MDAT while file is not read-only
  - Invalid IsoMedia File
  - [MPEG-2 TS] TS Packet 1 is scrambled - not supported
  - [MPEG-2 TS] TS Packet 2 has error (PID could be 1792)
  - [MPEG-2 TS] TS Packet 3 does not start with sync marker
  - Error importing 4.mp4: Corrupted Data in file/stream
  - Cannot find HEVC start code
  - Error importing 4.h265: BitStream Not Compliant

A detailed log of my tryst with MP4box can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/u97hZvBS).

The logs of my tryst with ffmpeg can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/E6XFztmn).

Handbrake also refuses to process the file on account of `moov atom not found`.

How can I make this video download work?

Comment: The file is encrypted, so you'll need the decryption key. DId yt-dl download using ffmpeg or its native hls downloader?

Comment: The M3U8 manifest which I used to download this file is here: https://pastebin.com/Tqu9wbFJ

Comment: @Gyan it was the native HLS downloader with 2 extra lines of code to facilitate download of this video. Without these two extra lines of code, the video wasn't being downloaded. These two extra lines of code are as per this image: https://ibb.co/dbQmTN0

Comment: Use the ffmpeg downloader in yt-dl.

Comment: @Gyan I've tried using FFMPEG downloader for this website from where I'm downloading the video. However, it has never been able to download the videos completely. In most instances, it stops writing/appending the downloaded TS fregments to the output file. At other times, it simply refuses to download the TS fragments, throwing encryption-related errors. At most, it writes about 12 to 25 MB data of the over 600 or 700 MB data.

Comment: @Gyan I must apologize. The M3U8 manifest mentioned earlier wasn't the correct one. I don't have the correct one now.

Comment: @Gyan I think you'd be able to get more clarity by going through this issue: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/21806

Comment: @Gyan another issue with using the FFMPEG downloader in yt-dl or otherwise was this with this video stream, it was never able to resume the download from the last fragment. It mostly never was able to resume the download, in fact.